# How to add an overlay div on Youtube Iframe, when the full screen mode is on?

Tags: jquery, html, css, meteor-blaze, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the Meteor Framework along with Blaze templating.
Below is where I create a new youtube object and inject it in the dom.

```
    self.autorun(() => {
      let tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        window.player = new YT.Player("" + index + "player", {
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
          videoId: data,
          playerVars: { wmode: "opaque", controls: 0 },
          events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady,
            onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      };
```

This is the Html section where I am injecting my Youtube player Object.

```
   <div id="iframeContainer">
    <div id="{{index}}player"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issue I am facing is when I click on the full-screen button on the video, the overlay div is hidden and Z-index does not help either. I want to add an overlay even when the video is in full screen on a website.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I figured that we can actually request a div to get into full screen using requestFullscreen()
Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

In my case I just had to grab the container:
var elem = document.getElementById("iframeContainer");

and then add these following lines:

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  /* Firefox */
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  /* IE/Edge */
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers